# Using HashMap to load image for specific marker crashes

Tags: android, google-maps

After a long struggle to get this right i finally think that i am almost there.  In my app the user can tap on any point on the map and then take a picture and return a marker.  when tapping on the marker to display the full image, it displays only the latest image taken.  So After searching for a week now to resolve this I was told to use HashMap to store that image to that point and then use CustomInfoWindo to display that image.  So i had to change my code to this.  So now i am at a point where everything works up until the user returns from the camera intent then i get this error:

```
12-16 16:38:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15998): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 16:38:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15998): Process: com.test.testguide, PID: 15998
12-16 16:38:02.058: E/AndroidRuntime(15998): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure  delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity  {com.test.testguide/com.test.testguide.Test}:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options
```

However the position is there:

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions());
  marker.setTitle("title");
  marker.setSnippet("snippet");
  **marker.setPosition(point);**
  hash.put(marker, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Why would it give me this error?

**EDIT**

here is the InfoWindow code:

```
@Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

TextView title = (TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title);
TextView snippet = (TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
ImageView image = ((ImageView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));

title.setText(marker.getTitle());
snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

if(hash.get(marker) != null)
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(hash.get(marker)));

return myContentsView;
 }
```

**EDIT 2**

For My Camera Intent:

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
getApplicationContext().getDir(
getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
 "/" +getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)),new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"));
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

For My `onActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

try {
GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
{

 Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.title("title")
.snippet("snippet")
.position(point));
hash.put(marker, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the values on the MarkerOptions, not on the returned Marker.

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("title")
                                    .snippet("snippet")
                                    .position(point));
hash.put(marker, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but it still displays the ic_launcher inage and not the one taken by the camera intent.  i have updated my code  with the camera intent and onactivityresult.